# Ajax is being blocked because no origin is present, although it is present

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api, cors

I have coded a API with laravel on a subdomain called backend.example.com. If I try to get informations from my API from another subdomain called partner.example.com I have no problems to verfiy myself and get those informations. This is the Ajax request:

This is the Ajax for the main domain:

```
    var ajaxArray = {
        "fromDate": from,
        "toDate": to
        };

    console.log(ajaxArray);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ("https://backend.example.com/api/v1/leads/showAdmin"), 
        type: "POST",
        data: ajaxArray,
        crossDomain: true,
        headers : {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("api@example.com" + ":" + "123456"), 
        "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        error: function() { alert("Error"); },
        success: function(result){
            alert("Working");
        });
    }});
```

And this is my Ajax request from the subdomain which is wokring:

```
    var ajaxArray = {
        "fromDate": from,
        "toDate": to,
        "table": "no",
        "userID": 20
    };

console.log(ajaxArray);

jQuery.ajax({
    url: ("https://backend.example.com/api/v1/leads/show"), 
    type: "POST",
    data: ajaxArray,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers : {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("api@example.com" + ":" + "123456"), 
    "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    error: function() { alert("No"); },
    success: function(result){
        alert("Working");
    });
}});
```

But if I am trying to do exactly the same with the main domain called example.com I get this error:

> Failed to load https://backend.example.com/api/v1/leads/showAdmin:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

The question I am asking my self is why because I have allowed all ....
See here:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

Would appreciate any kind of help!
Kind regards

**UPDATE:**
This is my response and request header:

```
General:
Request URL:https://backend.example.com/api/v1/leads/showAdmin
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:94.130.239.164:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header:
allow:POST
cache-control:private, must-revalidate
content-length:0
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Mon, 05 Mar 2018 13:52:41 GMT
expires:-1
pragma:no-cache
server:nginx
status:200
x-powered-by:PleskLin
x-powered-by:PHP/7.2.2

Request Header:
:authority:backend.example.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/api/v1/leads/showAdmin
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers:authorization
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:https://example.com
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
```

And this is the Laravel Cors Library I am using:
https://github.com/asm89/stack-cors

All settings I have done regarding the Cors Library is above.

Comment: look in your browser's network tools and check the exact response you're getting and whether those headers are in fact present or not. And also you don't need `crossDomain: true` in your ajax options. It doesn't do what you probably think it does.

Comment: The request header is containing the origin example.com but the response header isn't. But that cannot be.. That isn't a error by my Ajax code.

Comment: Well in that case it seems likely the server isn't setting the headers properly. Can you _show_ us what is in the response headers please? Also I don't know Laravel particularly, and your PHP code is shown out of context - how is what you've set there designed to affect  the response. Can you point to some documentation about it so we can see if you've done it correctly?

Comment: Yeah, give me a minute

Comment: I have added the code :)

Comment: Yes, so as the error states there is no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in that response, or any of the other headers necessary to enable CORS. You need to configure the server to send those headers both in response to the actual request and also in response to the pre-flight OPTIONS request (the result of which is what you've posted above). Have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Thank you!